# ASP.NET: Why is my JavaScript object set to null?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, null, getelementbyid

I have a `<script>` that contains this line:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("<%= this.tblSelection.ClientID %>");
```

... but `tbl` always ends up being set to `null`.

The table is declared like this:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblSelection" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="0"
    cols="1" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; right: 0%">
```

Both the script and the table are in the same master page file.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: I should mention that this script is executed on `onload`

Comment: Is the script in the page before or after your table?

Comment: the script is in the head section, the table is in the body. The head comes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing your JavaScript code is executing before your browser has a chance to fully render the table. At this point, the DOM of the page will not be complete and the `getElementByID` function will not be able to find the table because it doesn't exist yet!

Do this experiment:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script language="javascript">

    function showTable() {

        var tbl = document.getElementById("<%= this.tblSelection.ClientID %>");

        alert(tbl);
    }

    showTable();

</script>
```

This will show you "null" when your page first loads. If you add a button to call this method again, however, you'll see that `tbl` gets populated.

```
<input type="button" value="CheckTable" onclick="showTable();" />
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. Do you know how to access the DOM in the onload event handler, or is there any alternative?

Comment: Sure. The page body's OnLoad event handler fires AFTER the body renders, so the object is available. Try: <body onload="showTable();">

The other option, which isn't nearly as elegant, is to put your Javascript block AFTER the body of the page.

Answer (score 1):

**Nick** is correct. The table is not parsed/constructed yet.
Try to move `getElementById` code to [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.
BTW, jQuery provides a nice wrapper around document events and more.

Here is code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $get('table-id').doManipulation();
});
```

Comment: Did MrGumbe solution helped? If so, probably your's table is placed in update panel, or something that loads after document-ready.
Btw, did you installed JQuery? $(document).ready is a JQuery extension.

Answer (score 1):

MrGumbe and Valera are right about the timing of your Javascript. But I've seen this happen for another reason. We have had instances where server-side logic set tblSelection.Visible=false which means it isn't even emitted to the browser. Client-side code like yours runs looking for the ID and bang.